# Help with site's layout on FF/Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, layout, ubuntu

I've been working on this site http://minta.jvsoftware.com/ and I have a problem in FF/Linux, everything looks fine but the search button is showing at the bottom of the search box, I assume it's because the spacing of the elements in the top bar are too wide and since they're all floated to the left it jumps to the bottom for lack of space.

The problem is I can't debug properly since I don't have a linux distro available for testing (I used browsershots) so I was wondering if anyone on linux could point me in the right direction, I'm almost sure that if I reduce the right margin on the address it'll fix but I'm not sure by how much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using P tags when you should be using <DIV> and <SPAN>?

Comment: I figured using `<p>text</p>` instead of `<div><p>text</p></div>` would decrease the elements used

Comment: But they are not paragraphs of text. <P> is not needed.

Comment: I see, I thought that I needed `p` tags every time I used text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make a horizontal menu that has a minimum of cross-browser hassles is to use the following pattern:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li>SOME TITLE</li>
    <li><a href="...">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">2</a></li>
    <li><input type="text" .../></li>
    <li><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu ul, .menu li {
   list-style=type:none;
   padding:0;
   margin:0    
}


.menu li {
    display:inline-block   
}  

.menu a {
     display:block;
    ....other styles....

}
```

You started off this way in your menu for the store hours, then half-way you went to DIVs.

If you continue this pattern using `<li>` to wrap each item in your menu you'll find that things will work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well the main issue was that I wasn't setting the text input's width in the css so the browser was rendering it with the default settings making it too large, but will definitely keep in mind Diodeus solution on using `li` instead of `p` tags for this kind of stuff.